# Using Django Rest Framework for only certain apps inside Django Application

Tags: django

I'm not sure if this is possible since an extensive search gave me nothing. Or I might be searching the wrong terms.

Now I have a few apps inside my Django application as follows:

```
--AppOne
--AppTwo
--ExtendedAdmin
manage.py
```

Now, `AppOne` and `AppTwo` use Django Rest Framework and its related Token Auth Mechanism. For the `extendedAdmin`, I'd like to use native Django Auth or even SessionAuth of DRF since I'm trying to add quite an extensive admin panel to the application. I've not been able to find a satisfactory way of customizing Django Rest Framework to work it's auth mechanisms only for certain applications. Is there a way to do this? If not, what should I be doing different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I know you cannot. Because django rest framework intercepts the url and then performs its own logic of token validation. But there are solutions that you can use to keep both Session and Token Authentication.

I am using this for all my projects -

1. I keep Session Authentication for all urls that will be accessed for normal browsing
2. and I use `api` urls with django rest framework to be prefixed with `/api` for my api urls

For example -

The Session Based login is at `http://<host>/account/login`
and TokenBased login is at `http://<host>/api/account/login`

The easiest way to make prefixed url for django rest framework is by using `Routers` - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter

Example -

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet): # just a sample view set
...

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'api/users', UserViewSet)
```

Comment: In this, what exactly is `UserViewSet`?

Comment: Just an example viewset